# How can I set my bluetooth headphones to use A2DP?

Tags: bluetooth, audio

Audio quality is suddenly absolutely terrible when I use my bluetooth headphones, and I absolutely have no idea why it happened.

I read in some forums that I (might) just have to make the hardware use High Fidelity Playback (A2DP), but the new Sound Settings for Hera doesn't let me change that anymore. What do I do?

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407447/how-to-force-a2dp-sink-when-wireless-bluetooth-headset-is-connected). I haven't personally checked, but it *should* be the same thing in Elementary. *Should be...*

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My solution was to install pavucontrol with
`sudo apt install pavucontrol`.

With this program, you can change the audio configuration of your headset to A2DP easily.

[image]